# Bash: Compare a partial hash of a variable to a fixed string

Tags: linux, string, bash

I got an environment variable %foo.

**And within a linux bash script I want to:**

- create a bcrypt (or sha256 or md5sum, it's just about sanity test) of it
- trim down to the first two characters of the hash
- compare those to a known output (hard-coded string)
- warn, if it does not match

I am just too dumb to properly chain things, but roughly like this:

```sh
...
if [ 'a0' != ${ $foo | bcrypt | awk '$1:0:2'} ]
  echo "Warn: typo in password?"
fi
```

Essentially it's meant as a smoke test (with comparing to the full hash being too much disclosure). (I do know, revelation still lowers security / eases brute-forcing around 30² or 250²-fold or so)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add "echo -n" to start of the pipe, and use substr in awk. Note '-n' is needed, otherwise the hash will include a trailing new line.

```
if [[ 'a0' != $( printf "%s" "$foo" | md5sum | awk '{ print substr($0, 0, 2) }' ) ]] ; then
  echo "Warn: typo in password?"
fi
```

Alternative, use bash instead of awk, and using 'here-string', you can write

```
hh=$(md5sum <<< "$foo")
if [[ 'a0' != ${hh:0:2} ]] ; then
  echo "Warn: typo in password?"
fi
```

Based on Kamil's suggestion for printf, possible to keep all logic inside the if, without the intermediate variable.

```
if [[ 'a0' != $(printf '%.2s' "$(md5sum <<< "$foo")") ]] ; then
  echo "Warn: typo in password?"
fi
```

Comment: Note that [printf is better then echo](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo). Prefer `printf "%s" "$foo"`